# Merging two projects

Tags: .net

I need to merge an older version of a time management project (to which I made all the skin and some other functionality changes to) with the current live version of the project.

What should be the next step after exporting the source code of the live version to [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion)? What is the easiest way of merging the two projects without making it messy? (Since very few functions are required from the live version.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have it into Subversion, you can use the `svn merge` functionality. But it is not magical, sometimes you have to resolve merge conflicts "manually" using a merge tool.

Having your project under version control is the only way not being messy, if something goes wrong you can get just any step or version back or compare the current version to any other version.

PS: There are some Perl/Python scripts to import source trees into svn (client side scripts). **If you did not add or delete files between two of your versions it's even easier**: make an initial commit with the oldest version, then copy your newer version over the first one, commit again and so on for other versions.

Answer (score 0):

You say that "very few functions are required from the live version" - if so, it may be easiest to have a Visual Studio window open for each project and then copy code from the old project to the new version. Bear in mind that this will inevitably be error prone, so be sure to test *everything* when you think you're done; also get a user to give it a test, too.

You mentioned Subversion, too - an alternative approach may be to use a Subversion merge. Depending on the user interface that you have (personally I like Tortoise) there will be a "merge" command that allows you to merge together two projects. Merge conflicts are shown with special markers.

A third approach is to use a product like [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) (there are others) to merge the projects. This will show you the differences between the projects and allow you to pick the versions you need.